# Prob. 3, Sec. 3.3 in Erwine Kreyszig's INTRODUCTORY FUNCTIONAL ANALYSIS WITH APPLICATIONS

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, inner-products, orthogonality

Can we find an example where $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a direct sum of two subspaces that are not orthogonal?

A vector space $X$ is said to be a direct sum of two of subspaces $Y$ and $Z$ of $X$ if each $x \in X$ can be expressed uniquely as a sum 
$$x = y + z,$$
where $y \in Y$ and $z \in Z$.

And, if, in addition, $X$ is also an inner product space, then the subspaces $Y$ and $Z$ are said to be orthogonal if 
$$\langle y, z \rangle = 0$$
for all $y \in Y$ and for all $z \in Z$.

Is there any general result of this sort about finite-dimensional inner product spaces?

Comment: Pick any plane through the origin and any line through the origin that (a) is not in the plane and (b) is not orthogonal to it.

Comment: You posted Ex. #1 from the same section half an hour earlier, and Ex. #2 in between. Do you think about these assignments at all?

Comment: Yes, I do. It's not that I've started looking at these problems for the first time only now. Rather, I've been at this material at least twice before. So when I haven't been able to figure it out on my own even this time around, only then have I posted these here. And, these are not homework assignments. This course I took and aced back in Spring 2010.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott can you please exhibit this process explicitly? I mean let's take a plane $\{ (\xi_1, \xi_2, \xi_3 ) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \colon \lambda_1 \xi_1+ \lambda_2 \xi_2 + \lambda_3 \xi_3  = \mu \}$ and a line $\{ (\alpha_1 + \beta_1 t,  \alpha_2 + \beta_2 t,  \alpha_3 + \beta_3 t) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \colon \ t \in \mathbb{R} \} $ such that the line does not lie in the plane. Then?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I must let you know that out of the TEN problems in Sec. 3.3 of Kreyszig that I've been studying over the last couple of days, it's only THREE that I've posted here, and even in those ones I've asked for specific aspects of the problems.

Answer (score 1):

Take plane and a straight lines in $\mathbb{R^3}$ passing through origin such that the line is not perpendicular to the plane and obviously not in the plane.

There is no need to do such a calculative thing. An easy way out is the following:

Just take the $xy$ plane in $\mathbb{R^3}$ (you know its equation) and write down the equation of the straight line passing through $(1,0,1)$ and origin and lying in the $xz$ plane ($t\to (t,0,t)$)

Comment: can you please exhibit this process explicitly? I mean let's take a plane $\{ (\xi_1, \xi_2, \xi_3 ) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \colon \lambda_1 \xi_1+ \lambda_2 \xi_2 + \lambda_3 \xi_3  = \mu \}$ and a line $\{ (\alpha_1 + \beta_1 t,  \alpha_2 + \beta_2 t,  \alpha_3 + \beta_3 t) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \colon \ t \in \mathbb{R} \} $ such that the line does not lie in the plane. Then?